# Apache Redirect http://dev.com to https://dev.com and similarly devws to https of devws

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl-certificate

We have two tomcats and apache running on same Server. Trying to redirect/rewrite dev to https of dev and devws to devws of https

========================

VirtualHost *:80
    ServerName dev.com
    Redirect "/" "https://dev.com/"
/VirtualHost

## similarly for devws

After this I've written the https configuration.

The Problem is Both the URLs are redirected to dev https. I've tested with only one redirect at a time and both work fine. but unable to configure for both redirects.

Is there any way to redirect/rewrite dev to https of dev and devws to https of devws

Sorry for any confusion.

Rajiv N

Comment: Show us the line for devws. You probably redirect to "https://dev.com/" there resp. used "ServerName dev.com".

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.com
    Redirect "/" "https://dev.com/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80><VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName devws.com
    Redirect "/" "https://devws.com/"
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Could it be that you have a second config for `devws.com` redirecting/rewriting to the wrong place? Also, paste what "curl -L http://devws.com/" shows.

Comment: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

The Second configuration we have is for port 443 for both dev.com and devws.com

Comment: <VirtualHost dev.com:80>
    ServerName dev.com
    Redirect "/" "https://dev.com/"
</VirtualHost>
Now only dev is redirected to Https and devws will run on http. Still not able to figure out why both are redirecting to https://devws.com